# How to include details log info in oozie email notifcation (hue --workflow--Editor)

Tags: hadoop, oozie

## CDH 5.5.2 (hue --workflow--Editor)

we created oozie workflow using  workflow editor (hue --workflow--Editor).
when ever workflow fails/kills email notification send to dev team.currently we have added simple text in Body of email. 
This is not helping much to team as there is no log info in the notification mail 
please let me know how to achieve this in oozie(hue --workflow--Editor)
or it possible add the link of failed node (ex:-
/httyps://mymachine:8080/jobbrowser/jobs/job_1456590566111_5905/single_logs)

Comment: I entered  ${https://<Oozie Client>:11443/oozie/}/?job=${wf:id()} in message body. after workflow failed no Email notification received.if  remove above command from message body received failed notification. i am missing any thing here please advice.                                                    .                                       note:- i tried to access in browser  (https://<Oozie Client>:11443/oozie/) gives Oozie web console is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the message body:

```
More details about the job : ${oozie_web}/?job=${wf:id()}
```

Make sure that oozie_web variable value is your oozie web client address.

Comment: I entered below  ${https://<Oozie Client>:11443/oozie/}/?job=${wf:id()} in message body. after workflow failed no mail notification received.

Comment: Before this have you ever get notification email about the failure?

Comment: yes i have received failure email notification , if add this email notification ${https://<Oozie Client>:11443/oozie/}/?job=${wf:id()}  i am not getting.

Comment: i tried to access "https://<Oozie Client>:11443/oozie/" in browser ,getting "Oozie web console is disabled" is this could be a problem. please suggest any logs/parameter need to be checked.

Comment: There are a few documentation around how to enable the web console. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/AG_Install.html "The oozie-setup.sh script options are:

Usage  : oozie-setup.sh <OPTIONS>"
         [-extjs EXTJS_PATH] (expanded or ZIP, to enable the Oozie webconsole)""

Answer (score 0):

HUE-2997 enables you to do the same from Hue3.10.

For now, try putting this in email action body and see if this helps.

${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}

Comment: i have put this in email body ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}
,after workflow failed received below message.
Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1].
...not giving full detail log info